# How to Display dynamic data in extension .net grid panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ext.net

I have a **Grid Panel** of **extension .net control** in my web application .Now the grid panel is bind with Store . I have **encrypted login user name** & the database stores encrypted login name . Now I want the grid panel to **show the actual decrypted data** in the field . But I have no idea regarding where to decrypt during building of grid data in extension .net controls. Plz help.

Comment: You mean in the database table you can see data encrypted

Comment: Can't you hook up the RowDataBound event and do it in there?

Comment: You will probably need to decrypt the data on the server before sending to the client.

Comment: I have put encrypted username in Mysql database as well , now I want the grid panel[extension .net controls] to show the decrypted username.

Answer (score 0):

Before the datasource of Source was bound, I simply called a for loop of Db data just like a **rowbounddata** event, & within that I decrypted my column(field) data. At last bind the latest datasource

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.getUserList(this.getUserFilter()).Count; i++)
{
  this.getUserList(this.getUserFilter())[i].LoginName = CommonUtilities.Decrypt(this.getUserList(this.getUserFilter())[i].LoginName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EightCharacterEncryptionKey"]);
}
this.Store1.DataSource = this.getUserList(this.getUserFilter());
this.Store1.DataBind();
```